# How to install tensorflow on ubuntu 16.10 having python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.10

Can someone will help me to install tensorflow on ubuntu 16.10 having python version 2.7?

Comment: sudo -H pip install tensorflow

Comment: It is giving me an error stating "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

Comment: Are you iron man?

Comment: Try installing the wheel from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl' assuming you are trying on x86.